# Are all amphoteric substances weak acids and weak bases?

Tags: acid-base, water, molecules

I saw as an example that water is amphoteric (to be more precise amphiprotic), and I came up with the following questions:

Is there any substance that acts as a weak acid and a strong bases at the same time, or vice versa?

If so, or if not so, please give some explanations on the possible reasoning using their structures.

Also I have another question which is quite related but too short to be posted as an independent question, so I will ask here. The necessary condition for a substance to be amphoteric, as I heard, is that for it should have a hydrogen atom in it, and also the molecule should either have a lone pair of electron or be negatively charged. I understand the conditions about hydrogen atom and an electron pair, but why can the negatively charged property possibly be a necessary condition for a molecule to be amphoteric?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OH- in NaOH is a very weak acid and O^2- extremely strong base, but NaOH melted with Na would produce Na2O and H2.

Comment: @Poutnik So is there any systematic rule for amphoteric substances or do properties differ for every substance?

Comment: Aside of amphoteric properties they share, their properties differ, but that is obvious. There must be 2 conjugate acid/base pairs that share 1 member.

Comment: @Poutnik Sorry I was being ambiguous, I was talking specifically about amphoteric properties

Comment: Ask yourself, what do acidities of 2 different hydrogens of the same molecule/ion structure have in common ? Nothing in general. They can reside on the same atom as one extreme, or can be separated by many different atoms as the other extreme.

Comment: @Poutnik Hmm could you please elaborate possibly with examples on what you said on your last comment? I'm afraid it's quite unclear to me.

Comment: @Poutnik And so can I understand your conclusion as saying that there is no general laws like amphiprotic substance should always have both weak acidity and basicity? Also the groups of amphiprotic substances in the Bronsted-Lowry context are limited but can I think that every molecule can always (theoretically) act as an amphoteric substance from Lewis acid/base point of view? Because it's merely about losing or gaining electrons.